# Optimal search, finding a point where the sum of distances to other points is the smallest

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I have k points and I would like to find a (different) point closest to them (the sum of distances between the new point and the given points is the smallest)

On the plane for eight points

[image: spread sheet image]

How to write a program that will get me such a point for k given points in n dimensional space (e.g 16 points in a 10-dimensional space)

[image: spread sheet image]

How to write such a solver?

However, I would not like to use ready functions, although I will accept such a solution

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. This platform is meant to help and not to solve your stuff so you can copy paste it.

Comment: @main.c I tried to use the "lpSolve" and "optim" functions but my skills are still too small and I can not write a working function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point for which the sum of the distances to other points is minimum is called the *spatial median* of these points, also called the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). It can be derived by the *Weiszfeld algorithm*, which is implemented in the R package `Gmedian`.

Let's try with your example:

```
library(Gmedian)

X <- rbind(
  c(3, 4),
  c(5, 3),
  c(1, 8),
  c(4, 6),
  c(6, 6),
  c(0, 1),
  c(4, 6),
  c(2, 1)
)

W <- Weiszfeld(X)
```

---

```
> W
$median
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 3.472091 4.607492

$iter
[1] 76
```

Here is how you can get the sum of the distances:

```
smedian <- c(W$median)
sum(
  apply(X, 1, function(x){
    sqrt(crossprod(x-smedian))
  })
)
# 21.95253
```

As you can see, the spatial median is different than the one you got (`(4,4)`), and the sum of the distances is smaller than the one you got (`22.84819`).

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent Thank you very much